# Destructuring assignment not working in IE 11 even after using babel plugins

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I have a situation where I am adding a middleware which contain destructing params
When opened in google chrome ,its working fine .But it simply fails in internet explorer
Here is my webpack config file

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var AppCachePlugin = require('appcache-webpack-plugin');

var appConfig= require('./config.js');
console.log("appConfig is ->>>",appConfig);
var appPort = appConfig.APP_PORT;//Port on which the application is running

process.noDeprecation = true;
var ASSET_PATH = '/'
module.exports = function(options) {
  var entry, jsLoaders, plugins, cssLoaders, devtool;
  console.log('options webconfig-->', options, 'directory name', __dirname);

  // If production is true
  if (options.prod) {
    console.log('production minification');
    // Entry
    entry = {
       veris:path.resolve(__dirname,'./VerisInstrument/js/VerisApp.js'),
       au680 : path.resolve(__dirname,'./Au680Instrument/js/au680App.js'),
    commondashboard:path.resolve(__dirname,'./CommonDashboard/js/CommonDashboardApp.js'),
       groups:path.resolve(__dirname,'./Groups/js/GroupsApp.js'),
       homepage : path.resolve(__dirname,'./HomePage/js/HomePageApp.js'),
       infohealthcheck : path.resolve(__dirname,'./Common/js/infohealthcheckapp.js')
      
    };

   
    // Plugins
    plugins = [// Plugins for Webpack
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
   }),
  //   new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true,comments : false,compress: {
  //   // remove warnings
  //   warnings: false,

  //   // Drop console statements
  //   drop_console: true
  // }})

    
      // new es3MemberExpressionLiterals(),
      //
      
    ];

  // If app is in development
  } else {
    devtool = 'source-map';
    // Entry
    // entry = [
    //   "webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:" + appPort, // Needed for hot reloading
    //   "webpack/hot/only-dev-server", // See above
    //   //path.resolve(__dirname,'./app') // Start with js/app.js...
    //   path.resolve(__dirname,'./VerisInstrument/js/VerisApp')
    // ];
  //   require("babel-core").transform("code", {
  //   plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
  // });
    entry = {
      main: [
        "webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:" + appPort, // Needed for hot reloading
        "webpack/hot/only-dev-server" // See above
      ],
      //path.resolve(__dirname,'./js/app') // Start with js/app.js...
     veris : path.resolve(__dirname,'./VerisInstrument/js/VerisApp'),
      au680 : path.resolve(__dirname,'./Au680Instrument/js/au680App.js'),
   commondashboard:path.resolve(__dirname,'./CommonDashboard/js/CommonDashboardApp.js'),
      groups:path.resolve(__dirname,'./Groups/js/GroupsApp.js'),
      homepage : path.resolve(__dirname,'./HomePage/js/HomePageApp.js'),
      infohealthcheck : path.resolve(__dirname,'./Common/js/infohealthcheckapp.js')
      
    };
    
    // Only plugin is the hot module replacement plugin
    plugins = [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      }
     }),
     new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()// Make hot loading work,
    ]
  }

  return {
    devtool: devtool,
    entry: entry,
    // output: { // Compile into js/build.js
    //   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    //   filename: "js/bundle.js",
    //   publicPath : '/'
    // },
    output: { // Compile into js/build.js
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      publicPath : ASSET_PATH
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
      {
          test: /\.js$/, // Transform all .js files required somewhere within an entry point...
          loader: 'babel-loader', // ...with the specified loaders...
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: {
          presets: ['es2015','react','stage-2','env'],
          plugins: [require('babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread'),require('babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring'),require('babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters')]
        }
          // query : {
          //   presets : ['es2015','react','stage-2','env']
          // }

        }
        , {
          test:   /\.css$/, // Transform all .css files required somewhere within an entry point...
          use : [
            {
              loader : 'style-loader'
            },
            {
              loader : 'css-loader'
            },
            {
              loader : 'postcss-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
          ] // ...with PostCSS
        }, {
          test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/i,
          loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
        },
        { test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
         loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
      ]
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    target: "web", // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
    stats: false, // Don't show stats in the console
    node: {
      fs: "empty"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code where it is breaking

```js
export default function createLogger({ getState }) {
  return (next) => 
    (action) => {
      const console = window.console;
      const prevState = getState();
      const returnValue = next(action);
      const nextState = getState();
      const actionType = String(action.type);
      const message = `action ${actionType}`;
      console.log(`%c prev state`, `color: #9E9E9E`, prevState);
      console.log(`%c action`, `color: #03A9F4`, action);
      console.log(`%c next state`, `color: #4CAF50`, nextState);
      return returnValue;
    };
}
```

Can any one help me if i am doing anything wrong in the webpack plugin configuration.

Comment: Fails how, with what error?

Comment: Fails on ({getState}), error in console is 'Expected Identifier' .Basically IE doesnot understand curly braces in parameters

Answer (score 5):

It's not supported in IE at all.  [See here for supported browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I haven't had to support IE for ages, till recently. It's crippling.