# Expected identifier in array variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, split

I still need my function to work in internet explorer for compatibility reasons. The rest of the browsers support my array variable: `var [sHour, sMinute, sSecond]` but internet explorer does not. below is my full function.

```js
function time_interval(start, end) {
  var [sHour, sMinute, sSecond] = start.split(":");
  var [eHour, eMinute, eSecond] = end.split(":");
  var s = new Date();
  s.setHours(sHour, sMinute, sSecond);
  var e = new Date();
  e.setHours(eHour, eMinute, eSecond);
  var a;
  if (s.getTime() < e.getTime()) {
    a = e.getTime() - s.getTime();
  } else {
    e.setDate(e.getDate() + 1);
    a = e.getTime() - s.getTime();
  }

  a = a / 1000;

  var h = Math.floor(a / 3600);
  var m = Math.floor((a % 3600) / 60);
  var s = a % 60;

  return (
    (h ? h + ' hour ' : '') +
    (m ? m + ' minute ' : '') +
    (s ? s + ' second ' : '')
  ).trim();
}

const example = time_interval("10:00:00", "10:30:00");
console.log(example);
```

an example of the values taken by my array var is for instance, `10:30:00`. This is why I added `.split`. How do I separate the arrays so that it is compatible and remove the Expected identifier error? I tried separating it in single variables but this does not work because of the split.

```
var sHour
var sMinute
var sSecond
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Destructuring assignment not working in IE 11 even after using babel plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43894368/destructuring-assignment-not-working-in-ie-11-even-after-using-babel-plugins)

Comment: not really, it just says its not supported for IE, there is no solution. what I need is to have it work IN internet explorer.

Comment: The solution is to not use [destructuring](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), of course. IE is an obsolete browser. Destructuring is not going to work there. You can use a tool to transpile your code to an older ECMAScript edition.

Comment: The `splitStart` binding in Ashley's answer shows a simple, effective technique for avoiding destructuring (as Sebastian suggests). Since you're processing more than one argument this way, it's probably smart to exercise the Don't Repeat Yourself principle by using a function that you can apply to each argument.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the ideal solution, but you could just refactor your code like this:

```js
var splitStart = start.split(":");
var sHour = splitStart[0];
var sMinute = splitStart[1];
var sSecond = splitStart[2];
```

You could also consider using a function and an object:

```js
function convertTimeArrayToObject(arr) {
  return {
    hour: arr[0],
    minute: arr[1],
    second: arr[2]
  }
}

var startObject = convertTimeArrayToObject(start.split(":"));
console.log(startObject.hour) // Will print the hour
```